# can not see any dags in Tez ui

Tags: timeline, tez

I can run hive on Tez,But can not see any job in tez ui.

And it will drive me Crazy!

[image]

and the user and name are null in timelineserver
[image]

the config is blow:
tez-site.xml

```
<property>
      <name>tez.history.logging.service.class</name>
      <value>org.apache.tez.dag.history.logging.ats.ATSHistoryLoggingService</value>
</property>
<property>
       <description>URL for where the Tez UI is hosted</description>
       <name>tez.tez-ui.history-url.base</name>
       <value>http://10.0.0.51:8080/tez-ui</value>
</property>
```

and yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.timeline-service.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.timeline-service.hostname</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.timeline-service.http-cross-origin.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.timeline-service.generic-application-history.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>yarn.timeline-service.webapp.address</name>
   <value>${yarn.timeline-service.hostname}:8188</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.timeline-service.webapp.https.address</name>
  <value>${yarn.timeline-service.hostname}:2191</value>
</property>
```

And the url:

```
http://10.0.0.51:8188/ws/v1/timeline/TEZ_DAG_ID  
http://10.0.0.51:8188/ws/v1/timeline/TEZ_APPLICATION_ATTEMPT  
http://10.0.0.51:8188/ws/v1/timeline/TEZ_APPLICATION
```

All of them,I just get the same reponse below:

```
{
entities: [ ]
}
```

Comment: I think you should update yarn-site.xml on your clinet ，keep same with RM

Answer (score 3):

In my case found that it was YARN ACL problem.
So the following helped me:

```
yarn.acl.enable = false
or
yarn.admin.acl = activity_analyzer,yarn,dr.who,admin
```

As a bonus, gathered full configuration for HDP 3.1 + TEZ 0.9.2:

YARN configuration:

```
yarn.timeline-service.enabled = true
yarn.acl.enable = false
yarn.admin.acl = activity_analyzer,yarn,dr.who,admin
yarn.timeline-service.webapp.address = <host>:8188
yarn.timeline-service.version = 2,0f
yarn.timeline-service.hostname = <host>
yarn.timeline-service.http-cross-origin.enabled = true
yarn.timeline-service.http-cross-origin.allowed-origins = *
yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled = true
yarn.timeline-service.entity-group-fs-store.group-id-plugin-classes = org.apache.tez.dag.history.logging.ats.TimelineCachePluginImpl
```

TEZ configuration:

```
yarn.timeline-service.enabled = true
tez.tez-ui.history-url.base = http://<host>/tez-ui/
tez.am.tez-ui.history-url.template = __HISTORY_URL_BASE__?viewPath=/#/tez-app/__APPLICATION_ID__
tez.history.logging.service.class = org.apache.tez.dag.history.logging.ats.ATSV15HistoryLoggingService
tez.dag.history.logging.enabled = true
tez.am.history.logging.enabled = true
tez.allow.disabled.timeline-domains = true
```

Hive configuration:

```
hive_timeline_logging_enabled = true
hive.exec.pre.hooks = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.ATSHook
hive.exec.post.hooks = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.ATSHook,org.apache.atlas.hive.hook.HiveHook
hive.exec.failure.hooks = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.ATSHook
```

HDFS configuration:

```
hadoop.http.filter.initializers = org.apache.hadoop.security.HttpCrossOriginFilterInitializer
```

Comment: Hi @Pavel . I want to keep `yarn.acl.enable = true` but tez-ui failed to display. Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for including all the necessary config! This worked with ``yarn.acl.enable = true`` for me also.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see in Timeline Server UI you do not have information about jobs. In Timeline and Tez UI, you can't see information about jobs that you ran before Timeline Server was enabled since Timeline Server uses LevelDB storage and should publish information during a job running.